# Duplicate and relay mail from postfix

Tags: email, gmail, postfix, relay

We currently use Google Mail for our teams email. We want to move to a self-hosted email server. Some of our team members prefer using Google Mails interface and asked if we could continue having their email come in there.

The only solution I could think of was to have our mail server relay the email onto Google's mail servers whilst keeping a copy of the email locally on the mail server.

Is this the recommended way to do this, or are we attempting something that should be avoided? Is it possible to relay mail whilst maintaining a local copy of it?